# Login a User via email - Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Within my application a User is created after a successful transaction

```
def create_real_user
return unless current_or_guest_user.is_guest?
generated_password = Devise.friendly_token.first(8)
@user = User.new(
  is_guest: false,
  first_name: params[:first_name],
  last_name: params[:last_name],
  email: params[:email],
  password: generated_password,
  password_confirmation: generated_password,
  braintree_id: @result.transaction.customer_details.id
)
@user.save(validate: false)
RegistrationMailer.welcome(@user, generated_password).deliver_now
```

end

And as you can see an email is sent out and it advises that a password has been set for them but if they wish to change it then visit a link

```
Your current password is <%= @password %> but if you would like to change it then please visit <%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_user_registration_path(@user.id) %>
```

So when clicking this i get to the login screen but i would like to have the user automatically signed in and taken straight to the page where they can edit their password.

How would i go about this?

Thanks

Comment: You want to use [`bypass`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FControllers%2FSignInOut%3Asign_in) option:   `sign_in @user, bypass: true`

Comment: How would i construct my link? `edit_user_registration_path(sign_in @user, bypass: true) ` ?

Comment: take a look into [different approaches](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password) provided by Devise. Not sure, which one is the most suitable (the third one uses `bypass`)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a quick fix for this but it's possible.

Include a route for this special login case...

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'token_link'
  end
end
```

This gives you a new helper method `token_link_user_path

You would need to create a `token` field in your User table when you create the record, and set it to some random value via a `before_create`

```
class User

  before_create :generate_token

  def generate_token
    user.token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)
  end
  ...
end
```

In your email include the link...

```
link_to 'access your account', token_link_user_path(@user.token)
```

In your User controller...

```
def token_link
  @user = User.find_by(token: params[:id])
  @user = nil if @user && @user.created_at < Time.now - 1.day
  unless @user
    flash[:error] = 'Invalid log in'
    redirect_to root_path
  end
  @user.update_attribute(:token, nil)
  ... do here any processing, renders, or redirects you'd like
end
```

Note how we wipe out the token_link after it's been used, to prevent it from beign used twice.  Along the same lines, we check that it's not older than a day since the record's been created.

Comment: thanks @SteveTurczyn so no need to override anything with Devise as this is all outside the scope of devise and our own custom functionality ?

Comment: Actually since devise supports expiring passwords they must have something similar that can be applied to purpose.  It probably would be better than what you and I are doing, since you're sending a password 'en claire' in unsecured email.

Comment: I'll see if I can track something down, or hopefully someone will post a better answer.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated